# ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, smtp, oracle-apex, sendmail

I'm trying to send email from oracle apex following
[Oracle Apex Mail doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_mail.htm#AEAPI342) using procedure APEX_MAIL.SEND but getting error **ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available** .
I have no idea how to configure/set the email instance setting and what else it needed. Now it taking default smtp localhost, port 25.

Comment: Is there an SMTP server running on localhost on port 25?

Comment: @JustinCave yah SMTP-Email service is running, i just restart again.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that it is not.  Are you sure you're restarting the service on the database server and not, say, running an SMTP server on your local machine?  From the command line on the database server, can you telnet to localhost on port 25?

Comment: getting error to run telnet command on 25 "couldn't open connection to the host, on port 25 -Connect failed" . What would be the solution for that .?

Comment: @JustinCave i tried to telnet on smtp.mail.com on 25, it run fine in CMD, but still not able to send email. In Instance setting i changed SMTP localhost into smtp.mail.com

Comment: If you can't connect to the server on port 25, that means that either there isn't a SMTP server on that machine and port or that some sort of firewall is preventing the connection.  Are you getting the same error when you use smtp.mail.com?  If mail.com has a SMTP server you can use, I'd expect you'd at least need to authenticate to it in order to use it which would likely require using the `utl_smtp` package rather than `apex_mail`.